# How to add subject and variables when sending emails from Python using smtp?

Tags: python, email, smtp, subject

With some help off of here, I've set up some code to send emails via Python using SMTP. However the subject does not work. How can I also print variable values in the email body?

```
        port = 587  # For starttls
        smtp_server = "smtp.server.com"
        sender_email = "sender@outlook.com"
        receiver_email = "receiver@outlook.com"
        password = "password"
        message = """ Subject: Subject

        This message is sent from Python."""

        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
            server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
            server.starttls(context=context)
            server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
            server.login(sender_email, password)
            server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Please could you inform me as to:

How to correctly add a subject so that it correctly appears when the email is sent

How to include a print of a variable

Currently the only thing which appears in the email is "This message is sent from Python"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SUBJECT = "SUBJECT of mail"
AGE = 18
message = "Subject: {}\n\n My age is {}".format(SUBJECT, AGE)
```

you can use format function of string in python to use variable. and \n\n is necessary to differ subject and message

Comment: In my Outlook app, using this method still shows the subject line in the main body of text. Subject reamains blank.

Comment: @TheoF how did you do it?

Comment: @THeo F same ...

Comment: @JMR I didn't manage to do it. My comment above is saying that I couldn't manage to get the subject line text to appear in the subject line. Instead it incorrectly appears in the message body. Therefore I'm still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a no brainer once you think that your Subject is nothing but a string as defined below:

SUBJECT = "This is an email for " + first_name

Where 'first_name' is the variable name of the recipient.

In my case, I create a list of recipients (first_name, last_name, email) as explained in this [page](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) from a csv file and send an email with a personalized subject, body and attachment using the created lists.